# Google cloud platform ssh keys

Tags: google-cloud-platform, ssh-keys

i'd like to manage my own ssh keys and i want to distribute my ssh keys on all my instances is there a way that i can add it to the project metadata or i have to add the keys to every instance metadata separately.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On Linux and MacOS workstations, you can generate a custom SSH keys using the **ssh-keygen** tool and **[PuTTYgen tool](https://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/latest.html)** on Windows.

You can either use **[project-wide public SSH keys](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/adding-removing-ssh-keys#project-wide)** to give users access to all of the Linux instances in a project or use **[instance-level keys](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/adding-removing-ssh-keys#instance-only)** to give users access to specific Linux instances, stored in metadata to access the instances.

Alternatively, you can also use **[OS Login](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/managing-instance-access)** to manage SSH access to Linux instances, but metadata-based SSH key configurations on those instances will be disabled.

Also read [risks of manual key management](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/adding-removing-ssh-keys#risks) and [Managing SSH keys in metadata](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/adding-removing-ssh-keys).

Comment: makes a lot of sense thank you!